# Dynamic info command looping through commands to find certain command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

So I wanted to make a dynamic info command with the help of my command handler, so basically it needs to loop through the command and check if the command is equal to `args[0]` and then displays the info of that command, currently I'm having trouble with checking if the command is equal to what the user has written,

my code;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const loadCommands = require('./load-commands')

module.exports = {
    commands: 'info',
    minArgs: 1,
    maxArgs: 1,
    info: 'displays info about commands'
    callback: async (message, args, text, client) => {
        let reply = ''
        const commands = loadCommands()
        
        for (const command of commands) {
          // Check for permissions
          let permissions = command.permission
        
          if (permissions) {
            let hasPermission = true
            if (typeof permissions === 'string') {
              permissions = [permissions]
            }
        
            for (const permission of permissions) {
              if (!message.member.hasPermission(permission)) {
                hasPermission = false
                break
              }
            }
        
            if (!hasPermission) {
              continue
            }
          }
                //Format the text
                let alias = args[0]
                const mainCommand = typeof command.commands === 'string' 
                ? command.commands
                : command.commands[0]
                const { info } = command
                reply += info
            }
            message.channel.send(reply)
            },
        }
```

I need it to check if the command that the user has written (=info <command>) exists and if it does, display the info for that command, if you need any other code like my command handler or the "load-commands.js" file let me know and I will show you, I tried to find some ways to do it but couldn't find anything that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it using a map. I also parse the command and return a command object.

```js
const commands = new Map();
commands["print"] = (args) => {
  console.log(...args)
}

const prefix = "!";


function parseCommand(content) {
  const [command, ...args] = content.trim().split(" ");
  return {
    command,
    args
  }
}

const userCommand = "!print Hello Test 1";
if (userCommand.trim().startsWith(prefix)) {
  const request = parseCommand("print Hello Test 1");
  commands[request.command](request.args);
} else {
  console.log("Message doesn't have bot prefix");
}
```